# Bigtable bulk insert

Tags: python, google-cloud-bigtable

Can I perform bulk insert in Bigtable using python.

I am using below method to insert which is very slow. I have millions of rows to insert.

```
def row(self, row_key, filter_=None, append=False):
    """Factory to create a row associated with this table.
```

Ref Document: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/table.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`mutate_rows`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/table.html#google.cloud.bigtable.table.Table.mutate_rows)

[Cloud Bigtable writes](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writes) has more details, and there's also a [Python example](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writing-data#batch).

Comment: Thanks a lot. @Gary

Answer (score 0):

if you are using happybase API with google-bigtable , you can use bigtable happybase batch method

```
from google.cloud import bigtable,happybase
client = bigtable.Client(project=my_project_id, admin=True)
bigtable_instance= client.instance(my_instance_id)
bt_connection = happybase.Connection(instance=bigtable_instance)
bt_table = bt_connection.table(my_bigtable_name)

bt_batch_actions = bt_table.batch()
for key,val in my_info.items():
    bt_batch_actions.put(key.encode('utf-8'):val.encode('utf-8'))
bt_batch_actions.send()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud python libraries now actually support batching with only one network request. It's called `mutations_batcher`, and the documenation can be found [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigtable/table.html#google.cloud.bigtable.table.Table.mutations_batcher).